# Apply function to nested numpy arrays without loops

Tags: numpy

I'm coding a genetic algorithm, and am having some problems with avoiding loops
when applying crossover to pairs of parents. What I have so far is close, but I
need some help with the last step.

The population is a 2d array, each individual being a 1d array:

```
pop = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
```

To get the pairs of parents, I use the below, so parents is a 3d array
i.e. an array of pairs of parents:

```
inds = np.arange(pop.shape[0]).reshape((2,2))
parents = np.take(pop, inds, axis=0)
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]]
 [[ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]]
```

Now I want to perform the crossover, which has signature

```
crossover: [parent1, parent2] -> [child1, child2]
```

where child is also a 1d array, each crossover results in 2 children

So given population

```
[p1
 p2
 p3
 p4]
```

I would like to get back

```
[crossover(p1,p2)[0]
 crossover(p1,p2)[1]
 crossover(p3,p4)[0]
 crossover(p3,p4)[1]]
```

Or, since it can be simply flattened

```
[crossover(p1,p2)
 crossover(p3,p4)]
```

I have tried to use `np.apply_along_axis`, but I think it is not possible to get it to
apply to a *pair* of parents, just one parent at a time (by using `axis=-1`).

Can anyone suggest any numpy only way to do this?

Additional info - this is the way I am currently doing it, with a list comp:

```
children = [
        crossover(pop[2 * i], pop[2 * i + 1])
        for i in range(pop.shape[0] // 2)
]
```

Comment: Whats the expected o/p?

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is just a convenience iterator, most useful when working with a 3d array.  It is NOT a speed tool.  It does not compile your function.  If you can't figure out how to rewrite `crossover` to work with the whole arrays, I'd suggest doing the obvious iteration with indices.

Comment: Hi @Divakar - o/p is output? I will add further info.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your comment. I know that it is not for speed. But I am trying to learn numpy, and how to use functions that make coding easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to get it to work, even tho it meant changing my crossover function a little.
By reshaping the pop array, you can concatenate consecutive rows.

```
pop = np.array([[0,1,5,6,7,2,3,4],[0,7,2,6,1,5,4,3],[2,5,1,7,0,3,4,6],[7,6,5,1,2,0,4,3]])
pop_resh = pop.reshape((pop.shape[0]//2, -1))

[[0 1 5 6 7 2 3 4]
 [0 7 2 6 1 5 4 3]
 [2 5 1 7 0 3 4 6]
 [7 6 5 1 2 0 4 3]]

[[0 1 5 6 7 2 3 4 0 7 2 6 1 5 4 3]
 [2 5 1 7 0 3 4 6 7 6 5 1 2 0 4 3]]
```

Now apply_along_axis can be used on each combined pair of rows, then reshaped to get back to the starting shape.

```
children = np.apply_along_axis(py_crossover, 1, pop_resh).reshape(pop.shape)

[[0 7 6 1 5 2 3 4]
 [0 1 6 7 2 5 4 3]
 [6 5 1 7 0 2 4 3]
 [7 6 5 1 2 0 3 4]]
```

I'm not sure whether I will use this or just stick to what I had with the list comp, but this solution might help someone else at least.